# How does Theft Act 1968 s 4 exclude trade secrets?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales

#### Information

> Information is not property. In *Oxford v Moss*<sup>10</sup> a civil engineering student copied an examination
> paper and then returned it.<sup>11</sup> The Court of Appeal quashed a conviction for theft as
> confidential information cannot be stolen.<sup>12</sup> The protection of confidential information is
> found in civil law where injunctions can be obtained to prevent its revelation. It should be
> noted that the Computer Misuse Act 1990 creates special offences which deal with people
> accessing confidential information held on computers. →1 (p.558)

> <sup>10</sup> (1979) 68 Cr App R 183 (CA).
> <sup>11</sup>Do not get any ideas!
> <sup>12</sup>[Law Commission Consultation Paper No. 150 (1997)](https://www.lawcom.gov.uk/project/misuse-of-trade-secrets/) suggested the creation of an offence of disclosing trade secrets.

I quote from the PDF mooted at footnote 12 above.

> 1.4 At present the criminal law gives no specific protection to trade secrets. In
> particular, trade secrets cannot, in law, be stolen: they do not constitute “property”
> for the purpose of the Theft Act 1968,<sup>11</sup> section 1 of which defines the offence of
> theft as the dishonest appropriation of property belonging to another with the
> intention of permanently depriving the other of it.

> <sup>11</sup> Notwithstanding that the Act defines property as including “money and all other property,
> real or personal, including things in action and other intangible property”: s 4(1). By
> contrast, a patent or an application for a patent is personal property (Patents Act 1977,
> s 30(1)) and so capable of being stolen.

[s 4](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60/section/4) is too long  to quote here. This paper doesn't explain how it excludes trade secrets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This paper doesn't explain how it excludes trade secrets?**

In the context of the linked paper, "trade secrets" refers to intangible information, not physical items as can be shown by the example given at para 1.6:

> For example, if a trade secret is on a sheet of paper, a wrongdoer who removes it may be liable for theft of the paper; but a person who merely memorises the secret, and subsequently misuses it, incurs no criminal liability.

This is almost identical to the circumstances in [Oxford v Moss](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_v_Moss) which determined that:

> Information is not property.

And as such, it cannot be stolen in [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) unlike some other jurisdictions referenced in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

### The reason is in your quote

> ... section 1 of which defines the offence of theft as the dishonest appropriation of property belonging to another with the intention of permanently depriving the other of it.

I can take your IP (copyright, patent, etc.) and use it unlawfully, but I cannot deprive you of it. You are still able to use your IP even if I have dishonestly appropriated it - I might have "stolen" it, but I didn't commit theft in doing so.

Comment: Hi again Dale. Thanks. Would "appropriate" be a more appropriate term than "stolen" in your last sentence?